# How to manipulate pandas dataframe rows / headers? How to label whether the price of a row is higher or lower than the previous price?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, rows

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                            NDAQ    NDAQ    NDAQ    NDAQ    NDAQ     Close_Price_Increase
                            open    high    low     close   volume
time                    
2020-08-26 09:30:00-04:00   130.71  130.87  130.39  130.86  1824
2020-08-26 09:45:00-04:00   131     131.71  131     131.22  3420
2020-08-26 10:00:00-04:00   131.13  131.13  130.76  130.76  508
...                         ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Date                        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume   Close_Price_Increase
2020-08-26 09:30:00-04:00   130.71  130.87  130.39  130.86  1824     ...
2020-08-26 09:45:00-04:00   131     131.71  131     131.22  3420     1
2020-08-26 10:00:00-04:00   131.13  131.13  130.76  130.76  508      0
...                         ...     ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
```

The data comes downloaded in this format. I'm using the Alpaca API to download said data and convert to a dataframe with this code:

```
df_ticker = api_alpaca.get_barset(
    symbols=['NDAQ'],
    start=pd.Timestamp(str(df_transposed['Interval_Date'].iloc[0]) + '-04:00', tz='America/New_York').isoformat(),
    end=pd.Timestamp(str(df_transposed['Interval_Date'].iloc[-1]) + '-04:00', tz='America/New_York').isoformat(),
    timeframe='15Min'
).df
```

I've tried:

```
df_ticker.rename(columns=df.iloc[0,2]).drop(df.index[0,2])
idx = df.Index(['time'], name='time')
idx.rename('Date')
```

to no avail.

I'm also trying to show whether the price for a given interval has increased (labelling it as 1) or decreased (labelling it as 0). I've tried:

```
def getPrice():
    i = 0
    row = len(df_ticker)
    for i in row:
        if df_ticker['close'].iloc[i]> df_ticker['close'].iloc[i-1]:
            i = i + 1
            return 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
            return 0
df_ticker.insert(loc=5, column='Price_Change', value=getPrice)
```

I don't think iterating through the dataframe is the wisest choice though.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df.reset_index() #now your first column date should go as column

new_names=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Close_Price_Increase']

df.columns=new_names #now you should replace old column names, remeber that number of elements in list (new_names) should be equal to number of columns in your df
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 11 elements, new values have 7 elements

Comment: as i have mentioned, your list should have same number of elements as your dataframe. It seems that your original dataframe has 11 columns, so your `new_names` should have 11 elements not 7

Comment: I sorted out the header names. Thank you. Any chance you would know how to compare rows to show increase / decrease?

Comment: if you want to show increase etc. you should have two dataframes to compare, ask another question or edit this one with `pd.DataFrame(data)` that we can work with

Answer (score 0):

Solved row-wise comparison with:

```
df_ticker['Price_Change'] = np.where(df_ticker['Close'] >= df_ticker['Close'].shift(1), 1,0)
```